# JQuery Datatable not working if <base href is in head section

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I have a HTML table which implements jQuery Datatable as shown below:

I am unable to load jQuery Datatable properly if there is `<base href=` tag is present.

If I remove this base tag it works all well with all css and functionality. 
I cannot remove this base tag this tag is needed.

Anyone has seen this problem? Any solution or workaround?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>ABC- ABCorp</title>
      <base href="/abcorp/">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
      </link>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <head>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            } );
         </script>
         <style>
            /* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
            th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
            div.dataTables_wrapper {
            width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
         </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>First name</th>
               <th>Last name</th>
               <th>Position</th>
               <th>Office</th>
               <th>Age</th>
               <th>Start date</th>
               <th>Salary</th>
               <th>Extn.</th>
               <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Tiger</td>
               <td>Nixon</td>
               <td>System Architect</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2011/04/25</td>
               <td>$320,800</td>
               <td>5421</td>
               <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Garrett</td>
               <td>Winters</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>63</td>
               <td>2011/07/25</td>
               <td>$170,750</td>
               <td>8422</td>
               <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Ashton</td>
               <td>Cox</td>
               <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>66</td>
               <td>2009/01/12</td>
               <td>$86,000</td>
               <td>1562</td>
               <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Cedric</td>
               <td>Kelly</td>
               <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2012/03/29</td>
               <td>$433,060</td>
               <td>6224</td>
               <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Airi</td>
               <td>Satou</td>
               <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>33</td>
               <td>2008/11/28</td>
               <td>$162,700</td>
               <td>5407</td>
               <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Brielle</td>
               <td>Williamson</td>
               <td>Integration Specialist</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>61</td>
               <td>2012/12/02</td>
               <td>$372,000</td>
               <td>4804</td>
               <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Herrod</td>
               <td>Chandler</td>
               <td>Sales Assistant</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>59</td>
               <td>2012/08/06</td>
               <td>$137,500</td>
               <td>9608</td>
               <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Rhona</td>
               <td>Davidson</td>
               <td>Integration Specialist</td>
               <td>Tokyo</td>
               <td>55</td>
               <td>2010/10/14</td>
               <td>$327,900</td>
               <td>6200</td>
               <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Colleen</td>
               <td>Hurst</td>
               <td>Javascript Developer</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>39</td>
               <td>2009/09/15</td>
               <td>$205,500</td>
               <td>2360</td>
               <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Sonya</td>
               <td>Frost</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>23</td>
               <td>2008/12/13</td>
               <td>$103,600</td>
               <td>1667</td>
               <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Jena</td>
               <td>Gaines</td>
               <td>Office Manager</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>2008/12/19</td>
               <td>$90,560</td>
               <td>3814</td>
               <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Quinn</td>
               <td>Flynn</td>
               <td>Support Lead</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>22</td>
               <td>2013/03/03</td>
               <td>$342,000</td>
               <td>9497</td>
               <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Charde</td>
               <td>Marshall</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>San Francisco</td>
               <td>36</td>
               <td>2008/10/16</td>
               <td>$470,600</td>
               <td>6741</td>
               <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Haley</td>
               <td>Kennedy</td>
               <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>43</td>
               <td>2012/12/18</td>
               <td>$313,500</td>
               <td>3597</td>
               <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Tatyana</td>
               <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
               <td>Regional Director</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>19</td>
               <td>2010/03/17</td>
               <td>$385,750</td>
               <td>1965</td>
               <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Michael</td>
               <td>Silva</td>
               <td>Marketing Designer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>66</td>
               <td>2012/11/27</td>
               <td>$198,500</td>
               <td>1581</td>
               <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Paul</td>
               <td>Byrd</td>
               <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>64</td>
               <td>2010/06/09</td>
               <td>$725,000</td>
               <td>3059</td>
               <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Gloria</td>
               <td>Little</td>
               <td>Systems Administrator</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>59</td>
               <td>2009/04/10</td>
               <td>$237,500</td>
               <td>1721</td>
               <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Bradley</td>
               <td>Greer</td>
               <td>Software Engineer</td>
               <td>London</td>
               <td>41</td>
               <td>2012/10/13</td>
               <td>$132,000</td>
               <td>2558</td>
               <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Dai</td>
               <td>Rios</td>
               <td>Personnel Lead</td>
               <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>35</td>
               <td>2012/09/26</td>
               <td>$217,500</td>
               <td>2290</td>
               <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Jenette</td>
               <td>Caldwell</td>
               <td>Development Lead</td>
               <td>New York</td>
               <td>30</td>
               <td>2011/09/03</td>
               <td>$345,000</td>
               <td>1937</td>
               <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
   </div>
```

Comment: it's working for me fine (after replacing jquery library to latest-one). check your browser console and see any error is there?

Comment: Only `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` has the relative path here. Just use a CDN link for it as well, and you'll be set.

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you post your cdn or latest version numbers? Thanks

Comment: @RohanK  added as a solution